# Bundle identifier differs from reserved bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, itunes

I am trying to upload my app on itunes. For that I have created an app id and reserved a bundle identifier. In my project I have changed bundle identifier in info.plist file. But when I am trying to upload my app on itunes it is showing error that "Bundle identifier differs from reserved bundle identifier". I am changing the bundle identifier in info.plist but its showing the old one in the error. Is there any other place where we have to change the bundle identifier too? because changing the bundle identifier in info.plist is not doing the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. Once you correct your plist file to match your bundle ID on iTunes Connect you have to actually delete the contents of your build dir. Even just a clean command will not clear out the info.plist file in that directory. I deleted my project's build/Distribution-build folder and re-built and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The "reserved bundle identifier" is the Bundle ID assigned to the app when it's created in iTunes Connect - it'll either be the Certificate's App ID or for wildcard IDs one now has to enter a specific value. It appears that this bundle identifier cannot be changed in iTunes once it's been entered (even if the binary hasn't been uploaded).

Answer (score 3):

Change the bundle identifier name of the app to the reserved identifier in the Target-> info-> properties.

That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle identifier is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new version in iTunes Connect, then that version appeared in XCode. I've chosen it and everything went right!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the status on Itunes Connect is "Waiting for upload".

Xcode checks this for upload.

Comment: To improve the quality of your post you'll need to elaborate on this.