# Bundle Identifier Differs from Reserved Bundle Identifier

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning

I've spent a day on following up all the tutorials and suggestions on this topic to no avail, as when I issue an "Archive" all goes well and builds just fine. Along with with during the process I'm asked to allow "validate" the code.  However when I go to Organizer or try to up load it says "Bundle Identifier:  com.josephcampbell.sedonavortexhunting differs from reserved bundle identifier 8XXXXXXXXR.com.josephcampbell.sedonavortexhunting"

Now if I change  the bundle identifier in AppName-info.plist to 8XXXXXXXXR.com.josephcampbell.sedonavortexhunting and do Archive, it fails straight out saying 8XXXXXXXXR.com.josephcampbell.sedonavortexhunting doesn't match  com.josephcampbell.sedonavortexhunting!

I've looked at all the backposts, deleted files, rebuilt the projected, cleaned, and created new profiles on the Apple provisioning web site all to no avail (almost makes me want to switch to Android).  Any and all pointer would be appreciated!  Thanks, Joe...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385311/bundle-identifier-differs-from-reserved-bundle-identifier